# JPQL for Entities with No Items in ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

Simple JPA/JPQL question. I have an entity with a ManyToMany relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {      
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTablename="employee_project"
      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="employee_id"}
      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="project_id"})
  private List<Project> projects;
```

What is the JPQL query to return all the Employees that do not have any projects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from Employee e where not exists elements(e.projects)
```

or

```
from Employee e where size(e.projects) = 0
```

Comment: Hmmmm. I get an error with the first ("Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query..." using Eclipselink), but the second seems to work as advertised.

Comment: The first is invalid JPQL ... EXISTS requires a subquery to follow

Comment: @Andy - you're right, `elements()` doesn't seem to be in JPA spec, it's a Hibernate extension.

Answer (score 4):

JQPL does have dedicated `IS [NOT] EMPTY` comparison operator for checking is collection empty:

```
SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.projects IS EMPTY
```